# Sort ActiveRecord query response by Globalize3 translation on an association using locale

Tags: activerecord, internationalization, translation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, globalize3

I have two models and three tables total which are involved. Unfortunately, some renaming of the models from the original table names has occurred, so pardon the confusion.:

```
Symptom (chief_complaints)
SymptomName (chief_complaint_names)
(chief_complaint_name_translations)
```

The latter, of course, is used by Globalize3 to translate the :name attribute of the SymptomName model. Symptom has_many :symptom_names.

Consider the following:

```
Symptom.includes(names: :translations).order("chief_complaint_name_translations.name ASC")
```

This returns a mostly correct list, but it's sorting the list of Symptoms by the first translation name it encounters (despite my locale), and listing them by the correct locale.

```
# .to_sql output
"SELECT `chief_complaints`.* FROM `chief_complaints` INNER JOIN `chief_complaint_names` ON `chief_complaint_names`.`chief_complaint_id` = `chief_complaints`.`id` INNER JOIN `chief_complaint_name_translations` ON `chief_complaint_names`.`id` = `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`chief_complaint_name_id` ORDER BY chief_complaint_name_translations.name, chief_complaint_name_translations.name ASC"

# Actual SQL generated in the console
SELECT `chief_complaints`.* FROM `chief_complaints` INNER JOIN `chief_complaint_names` ON `chief_complaint_names`.`chief_complaint_id` = `chief_complaints`.`id` INNER JOIN `chief_complaint_name_translations` ON `chief_complaint_names`.`id` = `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`chief_complaint_name_id` ORDER BY chief_complaint_name_translations.name, chief_complaint_name_translations.name ASC
SELECT `chief_complaint_names`.`id` AS t0_r0, `chief_complaint_names`.`chief_complaint_id` AS t0_r1, `chief_complaint_names`.`created_at` AS t0_r2, `chief_complaint_names`.`updated_at` AS t0_r3, `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`id` AS t1_r0, `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`chief_complaint_name_id` AS t1_r1, `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`locale` AS t1_r2, `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`name` AS t1_r3, `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`created_at` AS t1_r4, `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`updated_at` AS t1_r5, `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`url` AS t1_r6 FROM `chief_complaint_names` LEFT OUTER JOIN `chief_complaint_name_translations` ON `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`chief_complaint_name_id` = `chief_complaint_names`.`id` WHERE `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`locale` = 'en' AND `chief_complaint_names`.`chief_complaint_id` IN (173, 2, 1, 224, 223, 3, 75, 4, 186, 15, 199, 201, 5, 177, 245, 94, 219, 225, 241, 6, 228, 213, 234, 164, 88, 26, 81, 7, 74, 136, 57, 21, 28, 18, 163, 165, 8, 112, 183, 147, 9, 160, 10, 64, 218, 170, 200, 207, 11, 175, 13, 138, 72, 12, 214, 239, 248, 14, 150, 190, 137, 16, 17, 154, 178, 127, 56, 206, 246, 101, 19, 20, 22, 96, 172, 255, 23, 24, 216, 25, 215, 29, 125, 113, 198, 195, 244, 27, 247, 132, 232, 70, 135, 133, 30, 31, 34, 32, 197, 181, 222, 208, 243, 35, 227, 196, 33, 36, 179, 53, 131, 126, 159, 58, 37, 202, 203, 38, 120, 68, 220, 230, 176, 39, 226, 148, 174, 91, 40, 41, 145, 151, 134, 189, 73, 43, 42, 47, 93, 44, 45, 46, 209, 192, 204, 205, 48, 188, 128, 49, 212, 249, 250, 211, 153, 50, 51, 52, 139, 187, 237, 109, 156, 129, 54, 157, 55, 87, 69, 84, 146, 60, 149, 221, 231, 242, 229, 59, 194, 240, 155, 61, 158, 62, 171, 180, 67, 63, 236, 65, 66, 162, 71, 152, 191, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82, 83, 103, 92, 98, 118, 85, 100, 89, 116, 114, 115, 104, 99, 111, 86, 97, 122, 251, 90, 238, 193, 254, 95, 252, 130, 235, 233, 102, 121, 123, 105, 106, 107, 108, 110, 217) ORDER BY name
```

You'll notice that there is no mention of 'locale' or 'en' in this query. If I do a query on SymptomName, including the with_translations method, passing the locale into it, it writes the query exactly as I expect it would.

```
>> SymptomName.with_translations(I18n.locale).to_sql
=> "SELECT `chief_complaint_names`.* FROM `chief_complaint_names` WHERE `chief_complaint_name_translations`.`locale` = 'en' ORDER BY name"
```

How can I *properly* inject the locale into the first query and have it sort my list of Symptoms according to the associated SymptomNames. It is worth noting that I have a method on Symptom that returns the first SymptomName it encounters.

I need this to sort the list by names derived from the locale AND to show the proper names. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update for anyone else using this gem. I was surprised to discover that the gem actually creates a new model on the fly for each model that has a translation. This new model has the same name as the original, appended with `::Translation`. So `SymptomName` would have a `SymptomName::Translation` model. This model has the translated attributes accessible, such as `SymptomName::Translation.first.name`.

Unfortunately, this new model does not seem to have direct access back to it's namesake as one might expect. There is no SymptomName::Translation.first.symptom`.

Reflecting on all associations does reveal a relationship to said model from the translation model, but the association is not available through the normal chain.

We ended up creating our own model to access this table called `SymptomNameTranslation`, adding the appropriate associations and joins as a default_scope. Seems to be working great, but would be nice to have this in the gem itself. Might be a good opportunity for a patch to said gem.